How can I create a dynamic update query in Postgres with plpgsql?
I want to build a query that can dynamically update tables, that is, receive a json with the fields that need to be updated.
I have something like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_update_multiple(
    table_name text,
    updates jsonb,
    id_value integer
) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
    set_clauses text = '';
    key text;
    value text;
BEGIN
    FOR key, value IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(updates) LOOP
        set_clauses := set_clauses || format('%I = %L, ', key, value);
    END LOOP;

    set_clauses := left(set_clauses, length(set_clauses) - 2);

    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET %s WHERE id = $1', table_name, set_clauses)
    USING id_value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

But I have not been able to test the function because when I create it I get this error:
SQL Error [42601]: Unterminated string literal started at position 0 in SQL ' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
What should I correct in my function?

Pretty sure it is the combination of  ... SET %s and set_clauses. You are passing a string literal to a parameter place holder.  Read UPDATE and use this form UPDATE weather SET (temp_lo, temp_hi, prcp) = (temp_lo+1, temp_lo+15, DEFAULT). Then you can separate the field names from the field values and use parameters for the latter.

I cannot reproduce the error with psql. Perhaps you are using a client that does not understand PostgreSQL's SQL dialect.

I mean, you tried to create the function and it let you create it correctly?

I'm trying to create it from dbeaver

Function created successfully with DBeaver (CE Version: 24.2.5.202411171748).

damn, what kind of stupid mistake am I making!!!!!

Try creating it using psql. Long term that is the better option, then you don't have to deal with DBeaver issues.

Thanks, it is indeed a problem with dbeaver. I was able to create it from psql :)

Probably not related to the reported error, but consider eliminating the local variables and replacing the function body with EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE %I SET %s WHERE id = $1', table_name, (SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT('%I = %L', j.key, j.value), ', ') FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT(updates) j(key, value))) USING id_value;.
